# Neo4j APOC remove trigger

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I need to delete APOC trigger. The following call works fine in case the trigger already exists:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.remove('RELATIONSHIP_INDEX_ADD_HAS_VALUE_ON');
```

but fails with the following exception:

> Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke
>   procedure `apoc.trigger.remove`: Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

if the trigger is absent.

How to properly try to remove the trigger and not fail in case it doesn't exist?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Please add an issue on github. https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/

Comment: added the bug https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/801